# Formatting data for Spark ML

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I'm new to spark and Spark ML.
I'm generated some data with the function  KMeansDataGenerator.generateKMeansRDD but I fail when formatting those so that it can then be used by an ML algorithm (here it's K-Means).

The error is

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data type ArrayType(DoubleType,false) is not supported.

It happens when using VectorAssembler.

```scala
val generatedData = KMeansDataGenerator.generateKMeansRDD(sc, numPoints = 1000, k = 5, d = 3,
        r =  5, numPartitions = 1)

val df = generatedData.toDF()

import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler

val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array("value"))
  .setOutputCol("features")
val df_final = assembler.transform(df).select("features")
df_final.show()

val nbClusters = 5
val nbIterations = 200
val kmeans = new KMeans().setK(nbClusters).setSeed(1L).setMaxIter(nbIterations)
val model = kmeans.fit(df)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VectorAssembler` accepts only three types of columns:

- `DoubleType` - double scalar, optionally with column metadata.
- `NumericType` - arbitrary numeric.
- `VectorUDT` - vector column.

You are trying to pass `ArrayType(DoubleType)` which is not supported. You should convert your data to supported type (`o.a.s.ml.linalg.DenseVector` / `VectorUDT` seems like a reasonable choice). For example:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf}

// Spark 2.0. For 1.x use mllib
// https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types
val seqAsVector = udf((xs: Seq[Double]) => Vectors.dense(xs.toArray))

val df_final = df.withColumn("features", seqAsVector(col("value")))
```